# Getting fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

Tags: macos, go, command-line-interface, istio, ventura

**Issue**: Due to 'bsdthread_register error' not able to execute 'istioctl' CLI.

It was working before, now getting below error while executing 'istioctl'

Error:
~> /opt/tech/installer/istio/istio-1.1.0> istioctl

> fatal error: runtime: **bsdthread_register error**

```
runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x269f246, 0x21)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81 fp=0x7ff7bfeff5d8 sp=0x7ff7bfeff5b8 pc=0x10297c1
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:129 +0x83 fp=0x7ff7bfeff608 sp=0x7ff7bfeff5d8 pc=0x1027343
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:501 +0xd6 fp=0x7ff7bfeff670 sp=0x7ff7bfeff608 pc=0x102c0b6
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeff6a8, 0x1, 0x7ff7bfeff6a8, 0x0, 0x1000000, 0x1, 0x7ff7bfeff890, 0x0, 0x7ff7bfeff899, 0x7ff7bfeff8d5, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 +0x1f4 fp=0x7ff7bfeff678 sp=0x7ff7bfeff670 pc=0x1052824
```

**Mac OS:** Ventura 13.6

**Istio:**

- Installed using: curl -L https://git.io/getLatestIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.1.0 sh -
- Set path @.zshrc
- *export PATH="$PATH:/opt/tech/installer/istio/istio-1.1.0/bin"*

**Go Installer:** Installed latest 'go' version using brew '*brew install go*'

- which go ~>  /usr/local/bin/go
- go version ~> go version go1.21.4 darwin/amd64

Tried installing istioctl different versions, but same error persisted

- Is there a way to fix on MacOS Ventura ?
- Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Hi All, After troubleshooting/debugging on 'GO' package upgrades & `brew update & brew upgrade` packages, finally able to fix **the fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error** & `istioctl` worked as expected.

**RCA**: 
- Installed latest Istio version [istio-1.20.0] via `curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -` & exported its PATH @ ~/.zshrc & also commented export PATH variable for the older version [Istio-1.1.0]

Thanks everyone !!!